# Ruta relativa en carpeta personalizada de un instalador web

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, .net, instalacion

He añadido un proyecto de programa de instalación web a mi solución, y necesito crear una carpeta justo en el nivel superior del directorio de destino de la instalación, llamada Shared.
En el sistema de archivos del equipo de destino, puedo agregar una carpeta personalizada pero en el DefaultLocation no me permite usar rutas relativas, sólo absolutas.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias.

Pongo un ejemplo:
Pongamos que un instalador instala en c:\inetpub\wwwroot\installDir\App1 otro en c:\inetpub\wwwroot\installDir\App2 y otro en c:\inetpub\wwwroot\installDir\App3. Lo que necesito es crear desde el instalador 1 la carpeta c:\inetpub\wwwroot\installDir\Shared que tendrá plantillas que compartirán App1 y App2

Answer (score 0):

Si has creado un `Setup Project` puedes agregar carpetas usando la opcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es una carpeta alg especial quizas debas usar `Custom Folder`

Si quieres una carpeta que este dentro de donde se instala la aplicacion podrias ver de crearla dentro de `Application Folder`, esa seria una ruta relativa a donde se instale la aplicacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Leandro, gracias por contestar. Edito mi pregunta para aportar más información. Efectivamente es un setup Project y pensaba que al añadir un custom folder podría usar ../Shared/ Pero no me deja usar rutas relativas.